# HashTable output coming double time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried the following code to bind the hashtable with listbox.

***.aspx:***

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Hashtable.aspx.vb" Inherits="Hashtable" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox><br />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***.aspx.vb***

```vb
    #Region "Namespaces"

    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net.Mail

    #End Region
    Partial Class Hashtable
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim ht As New Hashtable
            ht.Items.Add("1", "Sunday")
            ht.Items.Add("2", "Monday")
            ht.Items.Add("3", "Tuesday")
            ht.Items.Add("4", "Wednesday")
            ht.Items.Add("5", "Thursday")
            ht.Items.Add("6", "Friday")
            ht.Items.Add("7", "Saturday")

            For Each item In ht.Items

                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.key)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.value)

            Next    

        End Sub
    End Class
```

When executing, I got the following output:

in listbox,

```
 1 Sunday 2 Monday 3 Tuesday 4 Wednesday 5 Thursday 6 Friday 7 Saturday
 1 Sunday 2 Monday 3 Tuesday 4 Wednesday 5 Thursday 6 Friday 7 Saturday
```

Why is it appearing twice when I have used a single loop in my code? And what can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `onclick="Button1_Click"` from the `Button1` declaration in the aspx code since the code behind already states `Handles Button1.Click`, otherwise `Button1_Click` will be executed twice:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's true, I've tried the above code in Visual Studio and that's exactly the cause.

Comment: I have also created a sample project with a page that just contains a button and `OnClick="Button1_Click"` + `Handles Button1.Click`. But it is only executed once.

Comment: I have tested it with `AddHandler Me.Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click` in `Page_Load`. That would cause the handler to be executed twice.

Comment: Btw, here is this issue described: http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/19/onclick-and-handles-caution.aspx But as mentioned above, i cannot reproduce the behaviour. What framework are you using? I'm on .NET 4 (VS 2010).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm using .NET 3.5 (VS 2008)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think you were using a web application project instead of a website project, that's why you couldn't reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @ekad: that could be the reason.